# Is there a way to encrypt two messages into a single string?

Tags: python, cryptography

How do I encrypt two strings into one so that I can use two keys to get two different messages from a single string?

I need a method that should work kind of like this:

```
key1 = "asdf"
key2= "xcvb"
encrypted_message = "qpoweiurtz"

decrypt(encrypted_message, key1)
decrypt(encrypted_message, key2)
```

**Output:**

```
apple
pear
```

Is something like that possible?

Comment: See: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47857/is-there-any-way-to-have-a-coded-string-such-that-it-can-be-decoded-in-multiple

Comment: The obvious answer is a One Time Pad, though there are other issues with that, such as how to transmit the two separate keys.